# Django-Haystack not finding any field

Tags: python, django, django-haystack

I am trying to write a little search engine with django-haystac and whoosh.
I adapted their tutorial, I've created my index from a JSON file and query it successfully with QueryParser and now I'm trying to use their view.

when I try to access the search url at: http://127.0.0.1:8000/my_search/ I get the error:

The index 'PaperIndex' must have one (and only one) SearchField with document=True.

If I remove the search_indexes.py I can access the search page, but then of course it does not work as it doesn't have any indecies to search.

By debugging it seems it does not pickup any fields, but it does see the class.

I tried several things but nothing worked

my search_indexes.py:

```
from haystack import indexes
from my_search.models import Paper


class PaperIndex(indexes.SearchIndex, indexes.Indexable):
    """
    This is a search index
    """

    title = indexes.CharField(model_attr='title'),
    abstract = indexes.CharField(document=True,
       use_template=False, model_attr='abstract'),


    def get_model(self):
        return Paper

    def index_queryset(self, using=None):
        """Used when the entire index for model is updated."""
        return self.get_model().objects  # .filter(
            pub_date__lte=datetime.datetime.now())
```

my models.py:

```
from django.db import models


class Paper(models.Model):
    paper_url = models.CharField(max_length=200),
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200),
    abstract = models.TextField()
    authors = models.CharField(max_length=200),
    date = models.DateTimeField(max_length=200),

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title
```

thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Haystack uses an extra field for the `document=True` field.
The `text = indexes.CharField(document=True)` is not on the model, and haystack dumps a bunch of search-able text in there.

Haystack provides a helper method `prepare_text()` to populate this field. Alternatively, the template method can be used, which is simply a txt file with django template style model properties on it.

```
class PaperIndex(indexes.SearchIndex, indexes.Indexable):
    """
    This is a search index
    """

    text = indexes.CharField(document=True)

    title = indexes.CharField(model_attr='title'),
    abstract = indexes.CharField(model_attr='abstract'),

    def get_model(self):
        return Paper

    def index_queryset(self, using=None):
        """Used when the entire index for model is updated."""
        return self.get_model().objects  # .filter(
            pub_date__lte=datetime.datetime.now())
```

Comment: thank you very much! it works now but it does not show any result, I think because I've created the index from the JSON file and not thought a database. For what I understand now a DB is required to use it, am I correct? thanks

Comment: Yes, a DB is required. Sqlite is very easy to get started with and can be setup like a file in a django project.   Does the managment command `rebuild_index` work?

Comment: I was hoping to avoid it, as I was able to query the index directly after loading from JSON, but I now see that this is only for DB. I have SQLite working but  when I run rebuild_index I get this error:
```
django.db.utils.OperationalError: no such table: my_search_paper
```

Comment: Technically, the DB is not needed to use elasticsearch, but a temp DB like sqlite would be a nice way to quickly pass though data. You could also use elasticsearch-dsl to have more freedom and use ES directly.  https://elasticsearch-dsl.readthedocs.io

Comment: thank you very much I would look into that, and also try to fix the DB problem. I was hoping whoosh + haystack would be simple and fast but I did not fully understand what I was going into.  Really appreciate your help!